# Better way to do this in PHP

Tags: php

I currently have my htaccess file set to remove the file type so

```
www.example.com/home.php
```

would become,

```
www.example.com/home
```

I need to compare the url with one that I have saved in the database, I do this by,

```
if ($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) {
    $pageURL = str_replace('.php', '?', 'http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
}
else {
    $pageURL = substr('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, -4);
}
```

When I save the url in the database it gets saved as the current page url after the htaccess file has removed the .php, it is inserted using jquery ajax.

When I come to compare it, I need this to make it match in php as php doesn't take into account the htaccess changes.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Be clearer. What constitutes success/failure of this algorithm? How are we to know what's "better" when we have no idea of your requirements?

Comment: I dont see a .htaccess, a database, or even a real comparison. What are we meant to improve here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
$pageURL = rtrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.php');
```

This would give your url with `.php` removed whenever it appears at the end of the url.

Comment: Yes but when there is a query string the .php is in the middle, this is better, though thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/parse_url) function. You can use it to parse the URL into parts then modify the path component (e.g. remove .php). Then you can rebuild the URL from those parts using the [`http_build_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php) function.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that combining John's suggestion above of using `parse_url()` along with using [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) would be best -- trimming, truncation with substr, etc. isn't always as elegant as `pathinfo()`.